# How can I alter the universal line ending behavior globally?

Tags: python, windows

I want to write out all text files with LF as ending instead of CRLF on Windows. Not just for my code, but for all other third-party dependencies as well.

I know I can just `open(..., newline='\n', ...)` for my codes. But there are external packages that write files and they `open()` without such options, so those files are opened in [universal line ending mode](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) and ends up being written in CRLF.

How can I change the default behavior from CRLF to LF on Windows? Apparently trying to overwrite `os.linesep = '\n'` didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could monkey-patch `open`:

```
import builtins

orig_open = open


def my_open(
    file,
    mode="r",
    buffering=-1,
    encoding=None,
    errors=None,
    newline=None,
    closefd=True,
    opener=None,
):
    return orig_open(
        file,
        mode,
        buffering,
        encoding,
        errors,
        newline="\n",
        closefd=closefd,
        opener=None,
    )


builtins.open = my_open
```

Comment: Didn't work, it doesn't affect `open()` calls in imported libs.

Comment: @nedsociety And if you do the monkey-patch *before* importing other libraries?

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: @nedsociety Having looked at it more, it seems we need to use `builtins`. Have a try.

Comment: Now it's working but not as complete as I thought, for example the codes using `TextIOWrapper` or standard handles still need changes. I'll accept the answer because it can be extended to those cases as well, but I wonder if there's a less ad-hoc way to cover as much as possible.

Comment: @nedsociety If there is, I would like to know as well. :-) But AFAIK, Python doesn't have a unified I/O architecture. There are at least two methods of file access that I can think of that are more low level or separate from standard streams. First, the low-level functions in the `os` module. Second the the `mmap` module.